# Unity Variable has not been assigned Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot figure out the issue, I deleted then remade the PlayTab object, but it no longer works... It is telling me it has not been assigned, but it has to my knowledge. Relatively new to Unity programming, any help would be great, the script below.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {
     public GameObject Buttons;
     public GameObject CreditsPanel;
     public GameObject QuitPanel;
     public GameObject Options;
     public GameObject PlayTab;
     public Slider audiosl;
     public Slider graphicsl;
     public Toggle fullscreen;
     public string SceneName;

void Start (){
    QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel (100);
    //(int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Quality")
    AudioListener.volume = 100;
    //PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Volume");
    int qualityLevel = QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel();
    audiosl.value = AudioListener.volume;
    graphicsl.value = qualityLevel;
}
void Update (){
    Debug.Log ("Update");
    AudioListener.volume = audiosl.value;
    QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel ((int)graphicsl.value);
}
public void InGame(bool a){
    if (a == true) {
        Application.LoadLevel (SceneName);
    } else {
        //continue
    }
}
public void Play(bool a){
    Debug.Log ("Inside Play Function");
    if (a == true) {
        Debug.Log ("Inside If Statment");
        PlayTab.SetActive(a);
        Buttons.SetActive(!a);
        Animation pl = PlayTab.GetComponent<Animation>();
        pl.Play("EnterPlayMenu");
    }else {
        Debug.Log ("Else'd");
        PlayTab.SetActive(a);
    }

}
public void ShowMenu(bool a){

}
public void Option(bool a){
    if (a == true) {
        Options.SetActive(a);
        Buttons.SetActive(!a);
        Animation Opt = Options.GetComponent<Animation>();
        Opt.Play("OptionEnter");



    }if (a == false) {
        Animation d = Buttons.GetComponent<Animation> ();

        d.Play ("mainbuttonenter");
        Options.SetActive (false);
    }
    }


public void Credits(bool a){
    if (a == true) {
        CreditsPanel.SetActive(a);
        Buttons.SetActive(!a);
        Animation cr = CreditsPanel.GetComponent<Animation>();
        cr.Play("EnterCredits");

    }else {
        CreditsPanel.SetActive(a);
    }

}
public void Quit(bool a){
    if (a == true) {
        QuitPanel.SetActive(a);
        Buttons.SetActive(!a);
        Animation q = QuitPanel.GetComponent<Animation>();
        q.Play("EnterQuit");
    }else {
        QuitPanel.SetActive(a);
    }

}
public void Exit(bool a){
    if (a == false) {
        Option(false);
        Buttons.SetActive(true);
        CreditsPanel.SetActive(false);
        QuitPanel.SetActive(false);
        Options.SetActive(false);

        PlayTab.SetActive(false);
        saveSettings();

    }
    if (a == true) {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
public void saveSettings(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Quality", QualitySettings.GetQualityLevel ());
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Volume", AudioListener.volume);
}
public void FullScreen(bool a){
    if (Screen.fullScreen == a) {
        Screen.fullScreen = !a;
    } else {
        Screen.fullScreen = a;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the object binding in the Unity Game Object pane? It is never initialized, or does it lose the Playtab state at some point?

Comment: @SilasReinagel
What exactly do you mean by object binding in the inspector?

Comment: It is quite likely you have not assigned the relevant gameobject to the PlayTab field in the Inspector. Select the object this script is attached to and see if the PlayTab field has the relevant gameobject in it. If not, drag-and-drop it from the Hierarchy into the PlayTab field.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you have only defined the playTab variable, but not assigned it.

**EDIT:**

Try displaying it at start, then automatically hiding it via code. Probably Unity don't initialize objects that are not visible on scene from the start.

Comment: But its a game object, its attached to the appropriate game object. How do I assign it? The other ones work as is...

Comment: Oh right, you mean in editor. I have forgot about that possibility. From my experience Unity is sometimes weird. Did you check if this specific object is NOT hidden?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hidden'? Sorry I am very new to Unity.

Comment: Objects on scene can be toggled as hidden. Thats means they are on it, but are not displayed. It can trigger the error you are getting.

Comment: It's toggled so it's not displayed so that the script can display it or not display it. Is that what you are referring?

Comment: Try displaying it at start, then automatically hiding it via code.

Comment: @PrzemekLewandowski Can you edit that into your answer for others to find in future?

Comment: PlayTab.setactive (false);

and

PlayTab.active = false;

Are both not working, any help on setting it to inactive on start?